# Set Intersection Distributed Over Set XOR

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For any sets $A$, $B$ and $C$,  I'm trying to show that 
 $A \cap (B + C) = (A \cap B)  + (A \cap C)$, where the operation $+$ is defined as follows: $ A + B = (A - B) \cup (B - A) $

This is where I get

$$
\begin{aligned}
A \cap (B + C) &= A \cap (B \cap \overline{C}) \cup (\overline{B} \cap C))\\
 &= (A \cap (B \cap \overline{C})) \cup (A\cap (\overline{B} \cap C))\\
 &=  ((A \cap B) \cap \overline{C}) \cup ((A \cap C) \cap \overline{B})\\ 
\end{aligned}
$$

Then I'm stuck! :) Any hint please?

Comment: Some times, when you're trying to manipulate your way from expression (1) to expression (2), if you're stuck and don't know where to to next, it might pay off to leave it for the time being and work on expression (2) instead, and see if you can get them to meet in the middle. So you could try to see what you can do with $(A\cap B)+(A\cap C)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "$+$" you use is known as symmetric difference in set theory with standard symbol "$\bigtriangleup$". Here is the proof:
\begin{align}
(A\bigtriangleup B)\cap C&=((A-B)\cup (B-A))\cap C
\\
&=((A-B)\cap C)\cup ((B-A)\cap C)
\\
&=(A\cap C-B\cap C)\cup (B\cap C-A\cap C)
\\
&=(A\cap C)\bigtriangleup (B\cap C)
\end{align}